# Getting MySQL errors when referencing existing table

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm trying to create some very simple tables, one of them with a FK relationship to the other. But MySQL doesn't recognize a correctly created table that exists. I'm on MacOS 10.14, and used the DMG's for MySQLWorkBench and MySQL Community Server v8

Steps taken already:
-Stop/restart MySQL via MySQLWorkBench
-Stop/restart MySQL via MacOS System Preferences
-Drop tables
-Drop DB
-Run mysqlcheck
-quadruple check all spellings/cases
-reconfigure query structures to step through

```
/* Creating the building_t table */

CREATE TABLE building_t (
  buildingkey VARCHAR(10), 
  buildingname VARCHAR(50), 
  buildingaddress VARCHAR(150), 
  buildingcity VARCHAR(50), 
  buildingstate VARCHAR(2), 
  buildingzipcode INT, 
  buildingmanagerphone INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (buildingkey)
  );
```

**RESULT:**

> 16:43:17  CREATE TABLE building_t (   buildingkey VARCHAR(10),
>   buildingname VARCHAR(50),    buildingaddress VARCHAR(150),
>   buildingcity VARCHAR(50),    buildingstate VARCHAR(2),
>   buildingzipcode INT,    buildingmanagerphone INT,    PRIMARY KEY
>   (buildingkey)   ) 0 row(s) affected   0.0083 sec

**NEXT STEP:**

```
/* Creating the apartment_t table */
CREATE TABLE apartment_t (
  apartmentkey VARCHAR(10), 
  apartmentrooms VARCHAR(50), 
  buildingkey VARCHAR(10), 
  PRIMARY KEY (apartmentkey),
  FOREIGN KEY (buildingkey) REFERENCES building_t(buildingkey)
  );
```

**RESULT:**

> 16:45:44  CREATE TABLE apartment_t (   apartmentkey VARCHAR(10),
>   apartmentrooms VARCHAR(50),    buildingkey VARCHAR(10),    PRIMARY KEY
>   (apartmentkey),   FOREIGN KEY (buildingkey) REFERENCES
>   building_t(buildingkey)   )   Error Code: 1824. Failed to open the
>   referenced table 'building_t' 0.00069 sec

**NEXT STEP:**

```
/* Change the apartment_t create statement to remove FK */
CREATE TABLE apartment_t (
  apartmentkey VARCHAR(10), 
  apartmentrooms VARCHAR(50), 
  buildingkey VARCHAR(10), 
  PRIMARY KEY (apartmentkey)
  );
```

**RESULT:**

> 16:47:13  CREATE TABLE apartment_t (   apartmentkey VARCHAR(10),
>   apartmentrooms VARCHAR(50),    buildingkey VARCHAR(10),    PRIMARY KEY
>   (apartmentkey)   )    0 row(s) affected   0.0077 sec

**NEXT STEP:**

```
/*alter the apartment_t table to add the FK after the fact */
alter table apartment_t ADD FOREIGN KEY (buildingkey) REFERENCES building_t(buildingkey)
```

**RESULT:**

> 16:48:09  alter table apartment_t ADD FOREIGN KEY (buildingkey)
>   REFERENCES building_t(buildingkey)    Error Code: 1146. Table
>   'wildwood.apartment_t' doesn't exist  0.0011 sec

None of these issues should be happening, as all formatting is correct. Note that when I try to reference in the CREATE TABLE statement, the error is "failed to open..." but in the ALTER TABLE statement, it says the that the table to be altered doesn't exist.

Comment: So what's the problem???  I don't see any errors.

Comment: @eric They are in there *"Error Code: 1824. Failed to open the referenced table 'building_t'"* for instance

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue [in this MySQL 5.7 db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f55ErkPvgLL6Tf1YNYWJHr/0)

Comment: @Eric check the block quoted sections. I updated formatting to highlight them

Comment: You're not doing the different statements in different transactions, are you? To be sure, what happens if you issue `COMMIT` after each statement?

Comment: Using commit generates the same results. There's gotta be something wrong with the server setup, but I can't find anything that points to it